# How to hide seekbar of photo ,video, panorama, from Camera App. in Iphone?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, camera, uiimagepickercontrollermediatype

[image]

As shown Screen shot i want to hide seek bar from camera, when i choose to capture video from my App through UIImagepickerController but am unable to hide this video and photo option

Comment: set imagePicker.mediatype as kUTTypeVideo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use following code to get your expected output, set `mediaTypes` property as `[kUTTypeMovie as String]` to capture only video.

```
 let controller = UIImagePickerController()
        controller.sourceType = .camera
        controller.videoMaximumDuration = 30.0 .
        controller.allowsEditing = true
        controller.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeMovie as String]
        controller.delegate = self
        controller.isEditing = true
        present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
```